# How to fix "Extra arguments at positions #1, #2 in call" with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently developing my first iOS app and I have an error "Extra arguments at positions #1, #2 in call" at the last line of this code.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class NotificationsViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var notifications = [Notification]()
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    private lazy var uid = user!.uid
    
    
    func fetchData() {
        db.collection("users/\(uid)/notifications").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print ("No documents")
                return
            }
            
            self.notifications = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Notification in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                
                let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
                let description = data["description"] as? String ?? ""
                
                return Notification( title: title, description: description)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here the Notification model :

```
import Foundation

struct Notification: Identifiable{
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var title: String
    var description: String
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you have your own type `Notification`, based on your code -- can you show the code for that type?

Comment: And it's giving your the error on the line staring with `return Notification`?

Comment: Yes exactly the error pop at the line staring with return Notification

Comment: Just a quick side note: the code for mapping your documents will become *much* easier by using Firebase's support for Codable. See this article: https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-firebase-codable/.

Answer (score 1):

The code *should* be valid, but there are a few ways it could be going wrong (note: none of these is necessarily exclusive of the others):

1. Your file with `Notification` isn't actually added to your target. The compiler thinks you're referring to the `Notification` that's part of foundation.
2. You need to recompile your project to get Xcode to realize your `Notification` type exists.
3. There's a namespace collision going on because, as mentioned before, `Notification` is part of Foundation as well. However, the compiler should know to default to the one in your current target.

Comment: That's my suspicion as well. I recommend not using any terms that are or might be taken by the framework(s) or SDK(s) you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Related to but not exactly the same problem, if the struct members are declared as immutable "let" instead of mutable "var", then we seem to lose the automatically generated memberwise init(...) arguments for "let" members with default values. This indicates that init(...) is not truly an initializer but instead equivalent to the body of--rather than the initializer list--of a C++ constructor.

The following does NOT compile successfully:

```
struct LetStruct {
    let a: Int
    let b: Int = 0
    let c: Int? = nil
}

let letStructA = LetStruct(a: 1)
let letStructAB = LetStruct(a: 1, b: 2)         // compiler error: Extra argument 'b' in call
let letStructABC = LetStruct(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3)  // compiler error: Extra arguments at positions #2, #3 in call
```

...whereas the following does compile successfully:

```
struct VarStruct {
    var a: Int
    var b: Int = 0
    var c: Int? = nil
}

let varStructA = VarStruct(a: 1)
let varStructAB = VarStruct(a: 1, b: 2)
let varStructABC = VarStruct(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3)
```